# Why do these different outlier methods fail to detect outliers?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, outliers

I am trying to find the outliers by group for my dataframe. I have two groups: `Group1` and `Group2`, and I am trying to find the best way to implement an outlier method

```
data = {'Group1':['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B','A','A','B','B','B','A','A','A','B','B','B','A','A','A','B','B','B','A','A','A','A','A','B','B'], 'Group2':['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D','C','D','C','C','D', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D','C', 'C','D','D','D', 'D','C','D','C','C', 'D','C','D','C','C'], 'Age':[20, 21, 19, 24, 11, 15, 18, 1, 17,23, 35,2000,22,24,24,18,17,19,21,22,20,25,18,24,17,19,16,18,25,23]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 

groups = df.groupby(['Group1', 'Group2'])
means = groups.Age.transform('mean')
stds = groups.Age.transform('std')

df['Flag'] = ~df.Age.between(means-stds*3, means+stds*3)

def flag_outlier(x):
    lower_limit  = np.mean(x) - np.std(x) * 3 
    upper_limit = np.mean(x) + np.std(x) * 3
    return (x>upper_limit)| (x<lower_limit)

df['Flag2'] = df.groupby(['Group1', 'Group2'])['Age'].apply(flag_outlier)

df["Flag3"] = df.groupby(['Group1', 'Group2'])['Age'].transform(lambda x: (x - x.mean()).abs() > 3*x.std())
```

However, all 3 methods fail to detect obvious outliers - for example, when `Age` is 2000, none of these methods treat it as an outlier. Is there a reason for this? Or is it possible that my code for all three outlier detection models is incorrect?

I have a strong feeling I've made a foolish mistake somewhere but I'm not sure where, so any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: None of your values are outliers by your methodology, as you have sufficiently few data values that the "outliers" skew the mean and standard deviation enough that they lie within your range of `+/-3*stddev`. If you have a *lot* of values in each group, you will have better luck with this methodology.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I've increased the number of data to 55 and now it successfully records it as an outlier :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within its group, that age of 2000 just *isn't* over 3 standard deviations away from the group mean. The group mean is 239.666667 and the group standard deviation is 660.129722.

It might look like an obvious outlier to you, but you don't have enough data to label it an outlier by that standard.

Comment: Ah gotcha, that makes sense :) Out of curiosity, out of the three methods I have listed there which one is the best/most suitable?